# Expand Disqus comment module form as default view or trigger after template load

Tags: javascript, jquery, disqus

Is there any option to show full form as a default view in Discus comment module and also 'post as a guest' checkbox need to be checked. any help?

I have tried using 'onReady' callback but didn't work.

```
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = 'removed'; 
this.page.identifier = 'removed';
this.page.title = 'removed';
// this.callbacks.onInit.push(function() {
//  console.log('onInit');
// });
// this.callbacks.afterRender.push(function() {
//  console.log('afterRender');
// });
// this.callbacks.onPaginate.push(function() {
//  console.log('onPaginate');
// });
this.callbacks.onReady.push(function() {
    console.log('onReady');
    document.querySelector('.guest-details').classList.add("expanded");
    document.getElementById("view31_display_name").click();
    document.querySelector('.guest-checkbox input').checked = true;
});
```

console.log('onReady') is working others not

Console Errors: 
disqus.php:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: As the error says, this `document.querySelector('.guest-details')` returns null, aka the element(s) is not found. You could include you html in the question so we can make sure it's there.

Comment: div.guest-details is in default disqus form and others too. (eg: .guest-checkbox)